# How to check for empty fields

Tags: python

I have an input file where each line has 4 fields separated by commas. For example

```
a,b,c,d
```

Unfortunately, a small number of lines are broken and are missing fields. For example

```
a,,c,d
```

I currently use split to put the fields into a list.  How can I check if any of the entries in this list are now empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`all`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all), it will return `False` if there's any empty string. Otherwise `True`.

```
>>> all(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
True
>>> all(['a', '', 'c', 'd'])
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this if you need to know which field is empty:

```
emptys_list = []

for i in range(len(list)):
    if list[i] == '':
        emptys_list.append[i]

return emptys_list
```